# Saving file upload destination as private

Tags: files

I have a content type with a file field where I want the files to be private... I set the upload destination to private, but when the field instance is saved with features, this setting is not saved. How can I save this for use with an installation profile? (all other content types use public files)

Comment: make sure web user has permission to private folder.

Comment: Sounds like a features bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upload destination is not saved with the field instance, but with the field base. I was using an existing file field that was public. I needed to create a new field and define it as private and save that field base in my feature.